# javax.validation How get property name in a validation message

Tags: java, validation

I'm looking for a proper way to use property name inside validation messages, like `{min}` or `{regexp}`.

I've googled this question a few times now and apparently there isn't a native method for doing this.

```
@NotNull(message = "The property {propertyName} may not be null.")
private String property;
```

Has anyone experienced this before and has managed to find a solution for this?

**UPDATE 1**

Using a custom message interpolator should be something like:

```
public class CustomMessageInterpolator implements MessageInterpolator {

    @Override
    public String interpolate(String templateString, Context cntxt) {

        return templateString.replace("{propertyName}", getPropertyName(cntxt));
    }

    @Override
    public String interpolate(String templateString, Context cntxt, Locale locale) {
        return templateString.replace("{propertyName}", getPropertyName(cntxt));
    }

    private String getPropertyName(Context cntxt) {
        //TODO: 
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can always write a custom annotation that checks for null value and takes some property.

Comment: Sure, i thought about this, but not sure if is best choice. Once is not about a new annotation for checking null values. I'm thinking about some way to create generic messages, preventing create a bunch of validation messages one for each property. I've read about MessageInterpolator interface, but still don't know how use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to use two messages and sandwich your property name between them:

```
@NotBlank(message = "{error.notblank.part1of2}Address Line 1{error.notblank.part2of2}")
private String addressLineOne;
```

Then in your message resource file:

```
error.notblank.part1of2=The following field must be supplied: '
error.notblank.part2of2='. Correct and resubmit.
```

When validation fails, it produces the message "The following field must be supplied: 'Address Line 1'. Correct and resubmit."

Comment: Good solution.
Apparently there is no way to intercept property name on `MessageInterpolator.Context`. Anyway, thank you all, for your answers and comments. If i find one solution of this nature, i'll share with you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As another workaround, you may also pass the property name to the message text as shown below:

Add the validation message to the properties file (e.g. text.properties):

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=may not be null.
```

Then define the annotation in the code as shown below:

```
@NotNull(message = "propertyName {javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}")
private String property;
```