# Java validation: Cannot interpolate field name in validation message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, javax.validation

I tried the approach mentioned on [How get property name in a validation message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809402/javax-validation-how-get-property-name-in-a-validation-message), but cannot apply it to the following situation.

```
@Data
public class CompanyRequest {

    @PositiveOrZero(message = "validation.amount.positiveOrZero")
    int quantity;

    // code omitted for brevity

}
```

Here is my `*.properties` file having message:

```
validation.amount.positiveOrZero=The ${fieldName} value must be positive or zero
```

So, how can I use the property name in the validation message?

Comment: Does anybody else have any idea?

Comment: But I use `javax.validation` and I think that answer cannot solve my problem. Can it?

Comment: @İsmailY. Amigo? Any reply please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${fieldName}` could not be retrieved easily inside the annotation without major modifications inside the core mechanism that makes the evaluation.

An easier way to achieve what you want, considering that for each field the name would be different, is the following.

Inside properties file put the property

```
validation.amount.positiveOrZero= value must be positive or zero
```

And then define the annotation in the code as

```
@PositiveOrZero(message = "The quantity {validation.amount.positiveOrZero}")
int quantity;
```

**Edit:**
It seems that the property should not be defined in a simple application.properties file but in another file named `ValidationMessages.properties` in the classpath.

As documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html)

> setValidationMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) Specify a
> custom Spring MessageSource for resolving validation messages, instead
> of relying on **JSR-303's default "ValidationMessages.properties" bundle
> in the classpath.**

Comment: What about the parameter in the `properties` file?

Comment: @stack you need `{}` so that it loads the message from properties file. Where have you found in documentation that you can use the `${fieldName}` inside the message provided to annotation?

Comment: It returns `"{validation.amount.positiveOrZero}"`. I am not sure if I use the parameter correctly in the properties file. I used as `validation.amount.positiveOrZero=The ${fieldName} value must be positive or zero`

Comment: Normally I could read the text in the properties as `@PositiveOrZero(message = "validation.amount.positiveOrZero")` without any problem (not using curly braces). ANy idea?

Comment: @stack If you use `@PositiveOrZero(message = "validation.amount.positiveOrZero")` what does it output on validation failure?

Comment: If I use `validation.amount.positiveOrZero=The ${fieldName} value must be positive or zero` in the prop file, it gives *"org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [1] in public org.springframework."* error.

Comment: But, if I use `validation.amount.positiveOrZero=The value must be positive or zero` in the prop file, it gives *"The value must be positive or zero"*

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: @stack check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helps. But unfortunately it gives *"The quantity ${validation.amount.positiveOrZero}"*

Comment: @stack updated answer, please try it without the `$` inside annotation

Comment: It gives *"The quantity {validation.amount.positiveOrZero}"*.

Comment: I think we need to interpolate the variable rather than the message in properties file. I need to interpolate the name of the field and the message in properties. Something like `@PositiveOrZero(message = "${validatedValue} validation.amount.positiveOrZero")`

Comment: @stack No, this will pass the value, example : `-1  value must be positive or zero` . Check if the property is correctly defined in properties file

Comment: No, I just gave `${validatedValue}` as an example. So, what do you mean with "property is correctly defined in properties file"? Why do not you post all the necessary changes to your answer?

Comment: @stack this as posted in my answer `(message = "The quantity {validation.amount.positiveOrZero}")` is expected to work. Seems like the property `validation.amount.positiveOrZero` is not recognized in your project

Comment: @stack please check the `edit` in my answer

Comment: You rock!.. Voted up, but just a little issue. As I stated in my question, I need to grab `fieldName` in the message and create a message by using the name of the field automatically using a interpolation e.g. `${fieldName}`. Can I do that?

Comment: @stack this would require more changes in deeper core functionality which may affect other things that you don't want to be affected. That is why I would recommend if it is only for this simple annotation to use this solution

Comment: Yes, you right. I am just wondering if this solution supports internationalization. Does it?

Comment: @stack Yes according to oracle documentation you have to provide a different file for each Language and it would support internalization. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation-advanced002.htm